# Generate list of numbers to fit certain criteria

Tags: prolog

I had a predicate to generate a list of numbers,

```
generate_numbers(0,[]).
generate_numbers(N,[Head|Tail]):-
                    N > 0,                      
                    Head is N,                  
                    N1 is N-1,                  
                    generate_numbers(N1,Tail).
```

I am trying to modify it so that it generates numbers X and Y up to a limit. The conditions are that `1 < X < Y` and `S = X + Y` and `S < 100`.

I'm struggling to work out how to do it, I've tried but it's nowhere near correct.

```
generate_numbers(1,[]).
generate_numbers(X,[[Head,Y,S]|Tail]):-
                    X > 1,                      
                    Head is X,
                    Y is X+1,
                    S is X + Y,
                    X1 is X-1,                  
                    generate_numbers(X1,Tail).
```

I did have a check for `S > 100` but that stopped the code from working at all.

The output I'm after would be along the lines of `[1,2,3], [2,4,6], [3,9,12], [20,25,45]`. Obviously that's just a few examples, there will be 1000s in reality.

I think that I might need to recurse twice. So add 1 to X then keep adding 1 to Y until the limit is reached, add 1 to X and keep adding 1 to Y again until the limit is reached and keep doing this recursively. This should make sure that every possible pair is created.

Comment: You don't need to recurse twice. Your code already produces solutions based upon the calculations you defined in your `generate_numbers/2` predicate. However, your examples don't match your code. Your code says `Y is X + 1`, but that doesn't hold true for `[2,4,6]` (`Y` is `X + 2` here), etc. Could you please clarify what your requirements are?

Comment: Sorry, the second block of code I posted is my attempt at the solution but it is completely wrong. The requirements are all pairs of X and Y such that `1 < X < Y` and `S = X + Y` and `S < 100`.

Comment: This would be easily done using [CLPFD](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/~anderson/cs440/index.html/doku.php?id=notes:prolog2). Then use `findall/3` to collect the solutions if you need them in one, gigundo list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to approach this. The brute force way is to have a second layer of base case to iterate over one of the two addends in the summation. This solution will provide the list first in order of total sum, then by value of `X`:

```
gen_numbers(MaxSum, Result) :-
    MaxSum > 1,
    gen_numbers(2, MaxSum, 1, Result).

gen_numbers(Sum, Sum, Sum, []).            % 'Sum' has reached max value
gen_numbers(Sum, MaxSum, Sum, Result) :-   % 'X' has reached max value
    Sum < MaxSum,
    Sum1 is Sum + 1,
    gen_numbers(Sum1, MaxSum, 1, Result).
gen_numbers(Sum, MaxSum, X, [[X, Y, Sum]|Result]) :-
    Sum =< MaxSum,
    X < Sum,
    Y is Sum - X,
    X1 is X + 1,
    gen_numbers(Sum, MaxSum, X1, Result).
```

By counting up instead of down, I could keep the list in forward order and maintain tail recursion without the use of an auxiliary list. I constrained by `X` and the `Sum` and let `Y` vary. I think you could easily modify this to vary based upon whatever variables you wish.

A cleaner approach is to use the CLPFD library and specify the conditions as constraints:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

summation(Sum, [X, Y, S]) :-
    [X, Y] ins 1..Sum,
    sum([X, Y], #=<, Sum),
    label([X, Y]),
    S is X + Y.

gen_numbers(MaxSum, Result) :-
    findall([X, Y, S], summation(MaxSum, [X, Y, S]), Result).
```

Here, `summation/2` presents one of each solution at a time, and `findall/3` collects them. This solution is easily scalable to support more addends.

Comment: sorry to be a pain but X needs to be less than Y, so for example [99,1,100] should not appear. I've tried to fix this myself but can't seem to manage it. If you could have a look that would be great!

Comment: @JaAnTr I've taken the answer 95% of the way there. I think that sounds like the perfect exercise for the reader. If you think on it a bit, it shouldn't be an easy change.

Comment: Thank you I've done it now. I changed the last predicate and added one after it.
`gen_numbers(Sum, MaxSum, X, [[X, Y, Sum]|Result]) :-
    Sum =< MaxSum,       
    X < Sum,
    Y is Sum - X,
    Y < X,
    X1 is X + 1,
    gen_numbers(Sum, MaxSum, X1, Result).`
And the new predicate I added
`gen_numbers(Sum, MaxSum, X, Result) :-
 X1 is X + 1,
    gen_numbers(Sum, MaxSum, X1, Result).`